# InputSplit customization in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I understand that in Hadoop, the large input file splits into small files and gets processed in different nodes by the map functions. I also got to know that we can customize the `InputSplit`s. What I would like to know is if the following type of customization is possible for the `InputSplit`:

I have a large input file coming in to Hadoop, I want a subset of the file, i.e. a set of lines in the file to go along with every input split. I mean all the data chunks of the large file should contain these set of lines, irrespective of whatever way the file is split.

To make my question more clear, something like if we need to compare a part of the input file (say `A`) with the rest of the file content, in that case all `InputSplit`s that are going to the `map` function need to have this `A` part with it for the comparison.
Kindly guide me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically it would be possible to split your big file `(A, B, C, D, ...)` into splits `(A, B), (A, C), (A, D), ...`. However you'd have to write a lot of custom classes for this purpose. Currently the [FileSplit](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileSplit.java), which extends [InputSplit](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputSplit.java), basically says that the split for `file` begins at position `start` and has a fixed `length`. The actual access to the file is done by a `RecordReader`, i.e. [LineRecordReader](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java). So you would have to implement code, which will read not only the actual split, but the header (part `A`) of the file as well.

I'd argue, that the approach you're looking for is unpractical. The reason for which the record reader accesses the positions (start, start+length) only is data-locality. For a very big file, parts `A` and `Z` would be on two different nodes.

Depending on the size of part `A`, a better idea would be storing this common part in the [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html). In this way you could access common data in each of the mappers in an efficient way. Refer to the javadoc and http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#auxdata for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple explination for how the Hadoop MapReduce works.

Lets say you have a deck of cards and we want to sort them by suit and then by order, just like when you get a brand new deck.

Hadoop with 1 Mapper/1 Reducer

You take the deck and order it yourself

Hadoop with 1 Mapper/2 Reducers(going to map based on color, 2 colors, 2 reducers)

You take the deck, and give me all the black cards and someone else all the red cards. I order my cards and give them back to you and he does the same. You put the 2 together.

Hadoop with 2 Mappers/4 Reducers(going to map based on suit)

You and I split the deck in half the deck. We each sort our decks into 4 piles of each suit. Each person takes a suit and orders them. The 4 piles are returned and the final step sorts them how we want.

So yes, all the data in the "reducer" part has to have had some common piece, which is the piece that you map based on. Things one might map on is by day, or in my case by color or suit.

Comment: How does this relate to the OP's question about input splits and common data at the beginning of the file?

Comment: I am not sure of the OP's knowledge of MR system. Figured we would start real basic and build up from there based on any feedback from OP

Comment: Thanks for the explaining MR with example.. However I was looking for InputSplit issue on which harpun has provided an overview.